# Trigger "Run On Save" VS Code extension for any file in a directory tree

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VS Code extension [RunOnSave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) has several examples for how to trigger actions based on filename matches.  However, I have not been able to find an example of how to trigger based on a **directory name** match.

I am working on several files in a directory tree and I would like to rsync that directory to another server after any saves.

What pattern should I supply to the "match" argument in the RunOnSave configuration in order to only activate on files in a directory tree?

Comment: if you read the doc `"match": "some\\\\folder\\\\.*\\\\.*$"`

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I eventually found the following to work:

`"match": "/Users/me/my/dir/path"`

MacOS: 12.3.1
VS Code: 1.66.2